# Count of occurrences in two tables when joined in OracleDB

Tags: sql, oracle, join, count, oracle11g

I am stuck with this problem and it would be great if someone could help me out with this. I have two tables, AllMethods and RegisteredMethods. AllMethods has the total list of methods for a all projects. RegisteredMethods table has the list of methods of all the projects that are registered. The table structure is given below.

AllMethods Structure

```
Project_Name || Method names || Project_URL  
US_Project      method1         some_URL
US_Project      method2         some_Url 
US_Project      method3         some_url
Asia_project    method1         some_Url
Asia_project    method2         some_url
```

RegisteredMethods Structure

```
Project_Name || Method names || Project_URL
US_Project      method2         some_Url
Asia_Project    method1         some_Url
Asia_Project    method2         some_Url
```

Now i want to get the count of methods for all the projects in both the tables, so that i can compare the methods that has been registered to the total methods. I want to do this in one single query. The result that i am looking at is something like this.

```
Project_Name || Total_Methods || Registered_Methods
US_Project          3                  1
Asia_project        2                  2
```

I tried doing this with the below query:

```
select count(AllMethods.Project_Name), count(RegisteredMethods.Project_Name),AllMethods.Project_Name from 
AllMethods,RegisteredMethods where AllMethods.Project_Name=RegisteredMethods.Project_Name group by AllMethods.Project_Name
```

I am sure this is a grave mistake. :-)  Could someone please let me know the correct way of doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the aggregation before doing the join.  Otherwise you will get a cartesian product for each `Project_Name`:

```
select am.ProjectName, am.cnt as AllCnt, coalesce(rm.cnt, 0) as RegisterdCnt
from (select ProjectName, count(*) as cnt
      from AllMethods
      group by ProjectName
     ) am left  outer join
     (select ProjectName, count(*) as cnt
      from RegisteredMethods
      group by ProjectName
     ) rm
     on am.Project_Name = rm.Project_Name ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ought to do it:

```
select a.project_name,
       count(*) total_methods,
       count(r.method_name) registered_methods
  from all_methods a,
       registered_methods r
 where a.project_name = r.project_name(+) 
   and a.method_name = r.method_name(+)
 group by a.project_name;
```